# Messaging not working after executing the app in phone

Tags: android

I have developed an android app,in that i have a module to send text message which is a multipart message i used the following the following code.

```
             SmsManager sm=SmsManager.getDefault(); 
             ArrayList<String> p1=sm.divideMessage(quote1);
             sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null,p1,null,null);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Quotesent",1).show();
```

after i execute this application message is sent from the app.But i can't able to send text message from my messaging.I use Samsung S with ICS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the permission, add this to the manifest.xml

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: I have added the permission.I send the message from my app after i send,it gets received in the target mobile ,after that i cannot send any other message.After restarting the mobile i can send the message.Is there any prolem in the buffer that sends the message.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following code works.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null,
                            null);
```

**NOTE:** If this too not works, then something's wrong with your device! Don't forget the permission in manifest